# Python OpenCV Output Image's orientation、albedo、depth

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use python OpenCV output a picture's following data
1.orientation as a color map
2.albedo as a color map
3.depth file as a text file

Please help me, how can I do this?
sample image's data :light location(238,235,2360)
[Sample image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jOVr.jpg)

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you have images that represent orientation (and of orientation of what?), albedo and depth? If so, please show examples of those images. Any image can be assigned a color map. In fact, you can do that automatically with Mathplotpy. See https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

Comment: I suppose there is a link in the question that show the image.

Comment: Sorry, I have data for this sample image. (238,235,2360)